# Can I add a stackexchange login?

Tags: discussion, login

I see that now stackexchange has removed wordperss login, or at least it isn't showing on my system. But i'm not necessarily asking how to get that back, I recall there was some bug with that.  I had a similar bad experience in the past with myopenid being removed.

[image]

I can post from here because i'm already logged in.

I would like to add a stackexchange account 'cos at least stackexchange won't be removing that login method.

How can I do that?

This here offers a login but doesn't offer adding a stackexchange accoutn to your one.

[image]

If I enter an email for the one I want to add, it says "No account with this email found".  I see no option to add that login to my account.

Can I perhaps migrate my current account to a stackexchange account?

Comment: You need to sign out first. See [How to migrate a Google login to a StackExchange login?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/236956)

Comment: See also [Unable to "add more logins" - caught in login loop](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/238733)

Comment: Reading the above and similar links you might have to create a new account and then ask for an account merge.

Comment: ugh. coulda sworn they'd mentioned dropping that ages ago

Comment: @DavidPostill who and where would I ask? A new account has hardly any rep, can't comment, can't go into chat

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - though its been a while since I tested it. [Taken from my MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242263/move-login-for-existing-account/295987#295987)

It *sort* of works, though it is a little more convoluted that it could be.

You'd need to start by creating an account at the [Stack Exchange OpenID page](https://openid.stackexchange.com).

Login, check your profile page, and click on the link "Use your own URL to log in".

It'll give you a bit of HTML code

[image]

You need to copy the link on the *second line*

Now go to your profile, My logins, add more logins

[image]

And paste that into manually enter your openid.

Its *detected* as an SE login, and is handy when you stupidly delete yours testing things, like I did.